# How do I set schema for map field in big query?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have the following dataframe as output:

```
scala> df3.show()
+---+--------------------+                                                      
| id|        app_language|
+---+--------------------+
|101|Map(tamil -> 2, t...|
|103|      Map(oria -> 1)|
|107|     Map(hindi -> 2)|
|102|Map(tamil -> 3, h...|
|105|    Map(telugu -> 1)|
|106|     Map(tamil -> 1)|
|104| Map(malayalam -> 1)|
+---+--------------------+
```

I want to pass this result to output table in spark with the following command but its not working. (Seems to be an issue with schema for Map field)

```
  def createTableIfNotExists(outputTable: String) = {
    spark.createBigQueryTable(
      s"""
         |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $outputTable(
         |ds date,
         |id int64,
         |app_language MAP<string, int64>
         |)
         |PARTITION BY ds
         |CLUSTER BY user_id
       """.stripMargin)
    
  }
```

Comment: bigquery doesn't seem to have a map data type...maybe you can save it as a json string instead

Comment: @mck how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery doesn't seem to have a map data type, but you can save that column as a json string instead. For example,

```
val df4 = df3.withColumn("app_language", to_json($"app_language"))
```

And your create table definition will have a string type column instead:

```
def createTableIfNotExists(outputTable: String) = {
    spark.createBigQueryTable(
      s"""
         |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $outputTable(
         |ds date,
         |id int64,
         |app_language string
         |)
         |PARTITION BY ds
         |CLUSTER BY user_id
       """.stripMargin)
    
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But the requirement is to have that field as Map or an array of struct which has a list of app_language along with the count.